# Is there a way to render these dynamic divs with the same width of the first four?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

As you can see in this Tailwind REPL: https://play.tailwindcss.com/in8MDw0Zwb

the 5, 6 and 7 div are bigger than the 1, 2, 3 and 4.

Is there a way to render them with the same width of the first four and centering them?

I cannot control how many divs are there on each render. All is dynamic.

[image]

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div class="bg-gray-300 p-20">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-6 bg-red-400">
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">1</div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">2</div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">3</div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">4</div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">5</div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">6</div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked your code an I came up with something. Although there should be better ways to do this.

```
 <div class="bg-gray-300 p-20">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap justify-center gap-6 bg-red-400">
    <div class="max-w-[20%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">1</div>
    <div class="max-w-[20%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">2</div>
    <div class="max-w-[20%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">3</div>
    <div class="max-w-[20%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">4</div>
    <div class="max-w-[20%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">5</div>
    <div class="max-w-[20%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">6</div>
    <div class="max-w-[20%] flex-shrink-0 flex-grow basis-1/5 bg-white text-center">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The elements are dynamic.

Comment: Well in that case I suggest you use max-w-[20%] for all elements and put a justify-center for the parent element this could help